Error SSL Cert for email
My config: CentOS Linux 7.9.2009 (Core)/ Plesk Obsidian 18.0.64 Web Pro Edition/ Courier/ Postfix/ I have multi domain. Every domain havs a unique ip
I recive this error:

couriertls: read: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate

I can sent mail on smtp (465) but not recive email in thunderbird. Can someone help me?

Is the name you use to connect the same as the common name and/or one of the subject-alternate-names on the certificate?

Where do you get this error? What is it connecting to? What is the config?

Well, the error basically points to a problem with the certificate... It means the certificate doesn’t fit or something is wrong with it.
Is SSL set up correctly? If each domain has its own IP address, you need to make sure the right certificate is assigned to each of them. Check this in Plesk — all domains should have valid certificates.
The second thing, could it be that you’re somehow using SSLv3? Since it’s outdated, it’s better to use TLS instead.
For Courier, in the files /etc/courier/imapd-ssl and /etc/courier/pop3d-ssl, add: TLS_PROTOCOL=TLSv1.2.
For Postfix, in the file /etc/postfix/main.cf, add these lines:
smtp_tls_security_level = may  
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3  
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3

By the way, what do the logs say apart from the error?

i don't have  /etc/courier/imapd-ssl i have /etc/courier-imap/imapd-ssl i add the line but i still same error

did you add a value for postfix? and did you check the sll certificates?
